# Why captcha Image is breaking in drupal?

Tags: image, drupal, captcha

I am using module for captcha images in drupal and it was working fine but before some time it has started showing a image break icon instead of image.

I am not understanding why it is showing like this?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with me yesterday . You can try completely un-install the captcha and its related modules like re-captcha, image captcha etc. from uninstall tab. Then Install it again. This solves the problem for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the element (with firebug in firefox or f12 for chrome), what is the image's path? 
May be you have just to redefine the captcha image folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same problem and i found out that it is a fonts problem.

In the fonts settings, the default fonts wouldn't appeared. When i choosed "PHP built-in font" (The only one that showed a preview) it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error when migrating a site from another host.  I was getting an internal server error (http code 500).  The problem was that I was missing the PHP GD extensions.

On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```